# ROS Message details

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I want to know from where can I get the detailed information about the ROS messages. I know the use of rosmsg, but I want more information such as what exactly they communicate, in which packages are they included etc. I want to make use of messages in programming. So I would like to have all information that I need to program in C++.
Version: ROS Groovy

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80816/ros-message-details/) by [Jainendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6806/jainendra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no comprehensive list of all ROS messages because every new project can add messages. ROS defines a format for messages and the legal primitives, but messages can be defined and generated by users. See this tutorial for more: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

That having been said, there are a number of messages that come with the ROS installation that are generally useful. Like all packages, they are documented separately, but someone was kind enough to point to all of the key ones in the common_msgs stack (http://wiki.ros.org/common_msgs). Also look at std_msgs (http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs). Each of these pages have links to the necessary documentation that you will need to review to get the information you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) with karma: 320 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jainendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6806/jainendra/) on 2013-09-18**:
Thanks a lot for the answer :)